# Simple web server hangs on run

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

For a peice of work I have created a web server that handles multiple requests with threading however it now hangs when I run the program and I just cant work out why. It never reaches the stage of  print('Connected by', address). Any help and explination would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Connect(threading.Thread):

def __init__ (self, connection):
    self.clientsocket = connection
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

def run(self):
    stream = connection.makefile(mode="rw", buffering=1, encoding="utf-8")
    firstLine = stream.readline().split(" ")
    hList = []
    method = firstLine[0]
    path = firstLine[1]
    line = stream.readline().strip()

    while line != "":
        hList.append(line.split(":", 1))
        line = stream.readline().strip()

    if method != 'GET':
        stream.write("HTTP/1.0 405 Unsupported\n\nUnsupported")
    else:
        stream.write("HTTP/1.0 200 Success\n")
        stream.write("Content-type: text/plain\n")
        stream.write("\n")
        stream.write(str(firstLine) + '\n')

        for header in hList:
            stream.write(str(header) + "\n")

    stream.close()
    connection.close()
    return path == "/stop"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('', 9999))
s.listen(1)

while 1:
    connection, address = s.accept()
    print('Connected by', address),
    Connect(connection).start()
```

Cheers

Comment: Saying "sorry if the indentation is a bit messed up" is liable to mess up your Python program as well `;)`.

Comment: ...you're writing **Python**. Please fix the indentation.

Comment: That should be right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running your example with Python 2 instead of Python 3? In Python 2 `socket.makefile` does not have a `buffering` keyword argument. Your example works fine for me in Python 3.

Comment: I have tried using both 2.7.2 and 3.2.2 on pydev with eclipse, neither display the print message and just hangs.

Comment: Ah, Eclipse might be your issue then. Trying running it outside of Eclipse with Python 3.x.

Comment: Still not getting any results when running it through the python command line. The problem seems to happen at connection, address = s.accept() as anything before this point will print.

Comment: What platform/OS are you on? Seems to work fine on OSX/Linux.

Comment: Windows 7 right now but I have the same problem on xubuntu. I have tried both however I think I was using python 2.7 on xubuntu. The problem is allways that it hangs at that point.

Comment: Well, it's definitely Python 3 code, won't work with Python 2.7. I can verify it works with Python 3.2.2 on both OSX and Linux. You must be overlooking something.